# See the full list of posts, not external websites, +1ed in Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

Where do I go to find a list or collection of all the posts in Google+ that I have ever marked with the +1 button?

The +1 tab on my G+ profile shows only web sites I +1'ed and not the posts that I plussed when reading my stream.

Answer (score 9):

Google+ doesn't stream the posts you have +1ed. So you can't retrieve that list.

To Google, that +1 tab is for everything you have found around web and recommended. Inside Google+, +1 for the posts are just a feature to show the post owner that you like that post. That's all.

Comment: Unfortunately. AFAIK there is no such feature on FB either, that is I cannot find all the posts I've likes :(

Comment: @MichalStefanow for facebook, you can go to https://www.facebook.com/<USERNAME>/allactivity and select `Likes` from the top right dropdown. That'll show all your likes. Inside and outside FB.

Comment: It is now available In G+ new page design, the **Settings page** https://plus.google.com/settings gives a link to **Activity Log** https://plus.google.com/apps/activities that allows you to view all activities like "Posts", "Comments", "+1's on posts", "+1's on comments", "+1's on sites" etc.

Answer (score 7):

In case you're still interested, I found a way that you can see what you're looking for. In Google+:

1. Hover your mouse over the top left of the screen to open the Google+
   main navigation.
2. Select  Settings.
3. Scroll down to the Apps and activities section and click Manage apps and activities.
4. Select the Google tab at the top.
5. Click on the Google+ link in the +1's row.
6. You will see a list of all the +1's you have made. This won't apply to older posts, only +1's you've made after their last update (July 10th 2013...maybe??)

Hopefully there will be a way to get all +1'd posts, and in a better interface. [I got the instructions from this google help page.](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3113301?p=plusone_posts&rd=1)

Answer (score 4):

1. To see all your +1's on Google Plus posts, go to the link given below and click on +1's button: https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps/activities
2. To see all your +1's on external websites, click on +1's tab on your profile page. If it is not visible, then go to Google+ settings and enable the option to show this tab on your profile.

Answer (score 1):

You click on your profile picture to get to your profile, then click on "+1's" tab.

Like this...
[image]

Comment: Again, those are sites and pages out in the web that you have +1'd. It is **not** Google+ posts that you have +1'd.