# How do I view the posts I've +'d or Shared on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See the full list of posts, not external websites, +1ed in Google+](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25333/see-the-full-list-of-posts-not-external-websites-1ed-in-google)

Is there a way to view the post's I've "liked" or +'d on Google +

Answer (score -1):

If you are logged in:

1. Click "Profile" on the left vertical navigation
2. Click "+1s" below your profile picture

Comment: That's only external pages/sites that you've +1'd. It's not G+ posts.